# exception not getting caught when not in the right package in python

Tags: python, exception, package

EDIT:
OK, I managed to isolate the bug and the exact, complete code to to reproduce it. But it appears either something that's by design, or a bug in python.

Create two sibling packages: `admin` & `General`, each with it's own `__init__.py`, of course.
In the package `admin` put the file 'test.py' with the following code:

```
from General.test02 import run
import RunStoppedException
try:
    run()
except RunStoppedException.RunStoppedException,e:
    print 'right'
except Exception,e:
    print 'this is what i got: %s'%type(e)
```

and also in `admin` put the file 'RunStoppedException.py' with the following code:

```
class RunStoppedException(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        Exception.__init__(self)
```

In the package `General` put the file test02.py with the code:

```
import admin.RunStoppedException
def run():
    raise admin.RunStoppedException.RunStoppedException()
```

the printout:

```
this is what i got: <class 'admin.RunStoppedException.RunStoppedException'>
```

When it should've been `right`. This only happens when one file sits in the same dir as the exception, so they import it differently.

Is this by design, or a bug of python?

I am using python2.6, running it under eclipse+pydev

Comment: Perhaps you have two classes called RightException. The type of the exception you caught should have been 'admin.RightException.RightException' not just 'RightException'.

Comment: @Mark - that was my first guess, but no. I thought maybe it's the fact the module of the exception has the same name as the exception itself, so I included it in this example, but AFAIK this shouldn't matter.
@mikej - it's the same code, except for replacing the real name of the exception for "RightException". Other than that - the same code

Comment: Is RightException defined in a file called admin/RightException.py? Is this the actual code that causes the problem or just an example you've put together to illustrate what you're doing? Is the second except line actually except Exception, exception:? What version of Python? I would expect the message to actually read something like "this is what i got: <class 'admin.RightException.RightException'>" rather than just "this is what i got: RightException"

Comment: `%type(exception)` should be `%type(e)`.  Please post a complete code snippet that produces the behavior you see.

Comment: @mikej - yeah, it's the actual code, except for the name of the exception (I initially changed it since it is irrelevant to the problem - the real name is RunStoppedException).
You are right about the printout, I haven't copied that part but wrote it from memory. I'll edit it
I am using python2.6

Comment: Please make an effort to create a self-contained snippet, and then copy and paste it, and the output you get. It looks like there is a subtle bug somewhere, so it could be hidden from view by any little omission.

Comment: @Jouni - These are the best sinppets I can give - I am sure there is something missing, like I said, but I do not know where it is nor what to look for - that is actually what I am asking. When I try to run the most naive example (i.e with no extra code other than the code above), it does work as expected...

Comment: Please try harder, then. Without a reproduceable snippet nobody can answer your question. Most likely you are doing something stupid like defining the "same" class in two different modules.

Comment: OK, with your advice and encouragement, I have managed to find the exact reason, and reedited the question. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import admin.RunStoppedException
```

This is an ambiguous relative import. Do you mean `RunStoppedException` from the `admin` top-level module? Or from `mypackage.admin` when you're in a package? If your current working directory (which is added to the module search path) happens to be inside the package, it could be either, depending on whether Python knows it's inside a package, which depends on how you're running the script.

If you've got both `import admin.RunStoppedException` and `import RunStoppedException` in different modules, that could very well import two copies of the same module: a top-level `RunStoppedException` and a submodule `admin.RunStoppedException` of the package `admin`, resulting in two instances of the exception, and the subsequent mismatch in `except`.

So don't use implicit relative imports. They are in any case going away (see [PEP328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)). Always spell out the full module name, eg. `import mypackage.admin.RunStoppedException`. However avoid using the same identifier for your module name and your class name as this is terribly confusing. Note that Python will allow you to say:

```
except RunStoppedException:
```

where that identifier is referring to a module and not a subclass of Exception. This is for historical reasons and may also go away, but for the meantime it can hide bugs. A common pattern would be to use `mypackage.exceptions` to hold many exceptions. One-class-per-file is a Java habit that is frowned on in Python.

It's also a good idea generally try to keep the importing of module contents (like classes) down as much as possible. If something changes the copy of `RunStoppedException` inside the module, you'll now have different copies in different scripts. Though classes mostly don't change, module-level variables may, and monkey-patching and reloading become much harder when you're taking stuff outside of its owner module.

Comment: I have changed the code to refer explicitly to each location (see above) - still no dice. So I think your guess is wrong, though I agree that naming the module and class with the same name is bad practice

Comment: @bobince - Thanks! This looks like the right diagnosis for the problem (gonna dig into it a little further), only thing is, I don't get where am I making an "implicit" import. I am explictly spelling out, as best as I can, the path of the module. So I understand the problem, but not how to solve it, in this case (can't go any more explicit in my imports:)

Comment: The `import RunStoppedException` in `admin.test` in the new example is not explicit. If the top-level package is `admin`, it should be `import admin.RunStoppedException`.

Answer (score 0):

I can only see two reasons

1. You have two different Exception classes with same name
   **Edit**: I think culprit is this part because you import Exception class two ways

   - **from RunStoppedException import RunStoppedException**
   - **from admin.RunStoppedException import RunStoppedException**

   make them consistent and your problem will be gone.
2. You are using some IDE, which is interfering with your code, this sounds bizarre but try to run your code on command line if you aren't

Even 1 and 2 doesn't fix your problem, write a small piece of code demonstrating the problem, which we can run here, which we can fix, but I am sure  we will not need to because once you have written such a small standalone script where you can replicate the problem you will find the solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me:

```
[/tmp] ls admin/
RunStoppedException.py  __init__.py     test.py
RunStoppedException.pyc __init__.pyc
[/tmp] ls General/
__init__.py __init__.pyc    test02.py   test02.pyc
[/tmp] python -m admin.test 
right
[/tmp]
```

Running on:

```
Python 2.6.4 Stackless 3.1b3 060516 (release26-maint, Dec 14 2009, 23:28:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)] on darwin
```

My guess is that you have another "General" on your path somewhere, perhaps from earlier tests, and thats why the exceptions don't match.
Did you try the `id`/`inspect.getabsfile` debugging? If so, what was the output?

Comment: did you write your answer before I changed my question, since you can run the code for yourself now :) It appears something deeper, that the two inspections above won't resolve...

Comment: Edited now with test of your example